# Query to find 16 most clicked posts in last 30 days without duplicated categories

Tags: php, mysql

I have a seemingly simple task but I cannot seem to find an elegant solution using 1 query...

**Problem:** 
I have a table of recorded 'clicks' on 'posts', where each post is part of a 'category'.
I want to find the *16 highest clicked posts in the last 30 days* -- but I want to *avoid duplicate categories*.

It seems very simple actually, but I seem to be stuck.

I know how to get the most clicked in last 30, but I can't figure out how to avoid duplicate cats.

```
SELECT cat_id,
       post_id,
       COUNT(post_id) AS click_counter
FROM   cs_coupon_clicks
WHERE  time_of_click > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
GROUP  BY post_id
ORDER  BY click_counter DESC
```

I tried to get creative/hacky with it... it's close but not correct:

```
SELECT cat_id,
       Max(sort) AS sortid
FROM   (SELECT cat_id,
               post_id,
               COUNT(post_id)                       AS click_counter,
               CONCAT(COUNT(post_id), '-', post_id) AS sort
               FROM   cs_coupon_clicks
               WHERE  time_of_click > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
               GROUP  BY cat_id, post_id) t1
GROUP  BY cat_id
ORDER  BY cat_id ASC
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am not really a MySQL expert. I may end up just doing some PHP logic in the end, but I am very curious as to the correct way to approach a problem like this.

Thanks guys.

**EDIT (structure):**

```
CREATE TABLE `cs_coupon_clicks` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`src` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`cat_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
`post_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
`tag_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
`user_id` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`ip_address` char(30) DEFAULT NULL,
`referer` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`browser` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`server_var` text NOT NULL,
`time_of_click` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `cat_id` (`cat_id`),
KEY `post_id` (`post_id`),
KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**TEMP WORKING SOLUTION (HACKY):**

```
SELECT
  cat_id,
  MAX(sort) AS sortid
FROM (
  SELECT
    cat_id,
    post_id,
    COUNT(post_id) AS click_counter,
    RIGHT(Concat('00000000', COUNT(post_id), '-', post_id), 16) AS SORT
  FROM   cs_coupon_clicks
  WHERE  time_of_click > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
  GROUP  BY cat_id, post_id
) AS t1
GROUP  BY cat_id
ORDER  BY sortid DESC
```

Comment: would be better if you provide all related tables structures as well

Comment: Can we get a sample dataset to experiment with?

Comment: Why avoid duplicate categories?  Suppose all the categories but one were neglected completely.  Don't you want the highest 30 from the one category that did receive attention?

Comment: @JonathanBarlow I agree it is odd to ignore dups and I mentioned this, but it is what the client want :-/

Comment: @MattOgram just to clarify -- does each row with a given `post_id` have the same `cat_id`?  This seems to be denormalized.

Comment: There are times when what the client needs most is a competent programmer or designer to explain that what they are asking for will not result in meaningful information.  Tell them that it makes sense to know the top thirty in each category, or the top thirty overall, but it makes no sense to find out the top thirty if you're excluding the second highest question from each category.  That list of thirty  would essentially then just be a list of the highest in each category, even assuming there are thirty categories!

Comment: @MattFenwick - Yes, each `post_id` has the same `cat_id`. By denormalized do you mean that I should be doing a join to the main category table?

Comment: @JonathanBarlow - I will try my best to explain, I just think it's more for display purposes then actual use.

Comment: If it were more normalized, there might be `posts`, `categories`, `tags`, and `users` tables in addition to `cs_coupon_clicks`.  But, it is what it is.

Comment: @MattFenwick - Yes there are those tables. I did not create this db unfortunately... the `cat_id` is redundant I guess? I am starting to think I should be doing something like start with the category table and join to the most clicked coupons...

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy single query solution to this problem, it's a group-wise maximum kind of problem based on a temporary table (the one with counts) that would require self-joins.
Assuming your database grows big enough (otherwise just go for your php logic) I would go for a statistics table, holding info about categories, posts and click counts:

```
CREATE TABLE `click_cnts` (
 `cat_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
 `post_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
 `clicks` int(20) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`cat_id`,`post_id`),
 KEY `cat_id` (`cat_id`,`clicks`)
)
```

and fill it using the same query as the first one in the question:

```
INSERT INTO click_cnts(cat_id, post_id, clicks)
SELECT cat_id, post_id, COUNT(post_id) AS click_counter
      FROM   cs_coupon_clicks
      WHERE  time_of_click > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
      GROUP  BY cat_id,post_id
```

You could update this table using triggers or running update query periodically (do users really need info up to the very last second? probably not...) and save a lot of processing as finding most clicks for each category on indexed table requires a lot less time using a classic group-wise max approach:

```
SELECT cg.cat_id, cu.post_id, cg.most_clicks 
FROM
( SELECT cat_id, max(clicks) as most_clicks FROM click_cnts
  GROUP BY cat_id ) cg
JOIN click_cnts cu 
ON cg.cat_id = cu.cat_id
AND cu.post_id = ( SELECT cc.post_id FROM click_cnts cc
                   WHERE cc.cat_id = cg.cat_id
                   AND cc.clicks = cg.most_clicks
                   LIMIT 1 )
ORDER BY cg.most_clicks DESC
LIMIT 16
```

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark here. Did you try Select DISTINCT cat_id

Comment: Using DISTINCT is most likely the answer, but if they are getting duplicates they might want to take another look at the database architecture.

Comment: @wachpwnski true story my friend.

Comment: @MattOgram could you elaborate?

Comment: Distinct seems to do the same thing as GROUP BY, that was my first stab at this actually (still gets multiple categories).

Comment: @MattOgram could you give us a DESC table; I am assuming this is a relational database?  You might want to also add a SUM(click_counter) AS clicks GROUP BY <something>